# low quality movie with avconv

Tags: python, avconv

I want to create a movie from a sequence of images. I used avconv (linux System in our Company has only avconv and not ffmpeg package). to do that first I creates  'fig%0d.png' Images and then by calling subprocess command I create a movie:

```
subprocess.call('avconv -framerate 1 -f image2 -i fig%0d.png -c:v h264 -crf 1 Temp_electron1.mp4'.split())
```

but the Quality of the movie is not good and more importantly the movie doesn't Show the first Image and always starts from the second one.

I appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Try to force a pixel format`-i %d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p small_video.mp4` and then try to force a pixel format and remove the framerate restriction `ffmpeg -y -i %d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p  small_video.mp4`.

Comment: I used this :   subprocess.call('avconv -f image2 -i fig%0d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p 'video.mp4'.split()) but it see the eror: invalid syntax

Comment: Try to see all the available pixel formats `avconv -pix_fmts`. Also notice that your code has an extra ' character `'avconv -f image2 -i fig%0d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p **'**video.mp4'.split()`

Comment: thanks . now the Quality is much better but I don't know why the movie doesn't start with the first Image and always starts from the second one.any help?

Comment: can you repeat your test with another video? (http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_60fps_normal.mp4) maybe the problem it's your source video.